# How to configure Dante socks5 to use only specific users for authentication

Tags: authentication, socks-proxy, socks5

As I understand, if Dante is configured for using with **username** authentification method, then it gives the proxy access for all the system users.

I don't want to let every user to have the proxy access, but I want to give the access only to a specific user (or users).

Can I achieve this with Dante? If not, can you suggest what I can use for socks5 proxy with authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this with Dante.  You simply need to specify in the socks-rule what users you want to have access.

I.e., if your sockd.conf contains the following, literally except for "John", which you will have to substitute with whatever the real username is, only John will be allowed access:

```
socksmethod: username

socks pass { 
  from: 0/0 to: 0/0
  user: John
}
```

Comment: Please use our formatting tools to distinguish file contents from prose, and differentiate literal text from descriptive text.  For example, is the first line of your rule literally (s)(o)(c)(k)(s)(m)(e)(t)(h)(o)(d)(:)( )(u)(s)(e)(r)(n)(a)(m)(e), or is it `socksmethod:` followed by ***a*** username?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.